# Using PHP to change the format of a MySQL date

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have dates stored in a MySQL database like so: 2012-02-10

When i output them using PHP, is there a function I can use that will output it like so 10/02/2012

Ive tried:

```
$theDate = date_format($row['date'], 'd/m/Y');
echo $theDate;
```

but it doesnt seem to work. Any help appretiated.

PHP Version 5.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old way (non-OOP) to do it,

```
$t = strtotime('2012-02-10');
echo date('d/m/Y', $t);
```

Functions to check: [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime), [date](http://php.net/date)

Comment: Like the `old way` tag ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`date_create()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php) before using `date_format()`. This is because `date_format()` expects a [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) object as the first parameter.

```
$date = date_create($row['date']);
echo date_format($date, 'd/m/Y');
```

Another way to do the same thing:

```
$dt = new DateTime('2012-02-10');
echo $dt->format('d/m/Y');
```

For the PHP 5.4 users out there it can be simplified to:

```
echo (new DateTime('2012-02-10'))->format('d/m/Y');
```

**edit**

To comment on the alternative solutions provided, they can be simplified to:

```
echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($row['date']));
```

Just keep in mind that they do *not* account for daylight savings time or timezones like `DateTime` does.

Comment: Class member access on instantiation has been added in 5.4 version, not 5.5.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a really simple way to do it

```
<?php
    $theDate = $row['date'];
    echo date("m/d/Y", strtotime($theDate));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few examples:

```
$input = '2012-02-10';

// datetime (object oriented style)
$dt = new DateTime($input);
echo $dt->format('d/m/Y') . "\n";

// datetime (procedural style)
$dt = date_create($input);
echo date_format($dt, 'd/m/Y') . "\n";

// strtotime
$m = strtotime($input);
echo date('d/m/Y', $m) . "\n";

// substr
echo substr($input,8,2) . "/" . substr($input,5,2) . "/" . substr($input,0,4) . "\n";

// explode
$m = explode('-', $input);
echo "$m[2]/$m[1]/$m[0]" . "\n";

// preg_match
preg_match('~^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)$~', $input, $m);
echo "$m[3]/$m[2]/$m[1]" . "\n";

// sscanf
$m = sscanf($input, '%d-%d-%d');
echo "$m[2]/$m[1]/$m[0]" . "\n";
```

p.s. did I miss any? ;)